# No strings attached? Think twice! Which music video features a bird tied to a string?

Tags: language, music

It's 198-two.

I might be a white cocka-two.

Feeling caged, I try to brake free, from the 19th to the 21st: two seconds.

Only one thing on my mind, not two; stupid line between me and my cage too:

Break us into ...!

Comment: 21th? Cannot compute.

Comment: @Daedric U mean the orthography? This was non-intentional, and now fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Video is

> **[Joe Jackson - Breaking Us in Two](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n7IGRNWVQkc)** (1982)

Lots of references to

> the "Two" throughout the rhyme; the last line in particular (after the last edit) basically giving the title outright.

Early in the video we see

> a ***white*** bird (might be a ***cockatoo***? dubious; I think this is OP having fun), in a cage (***feeling caged***).  The woman in the video drops the birdcage and, ***from 00:19 to 00:21*** in the video the bird, ostensibly escaping its cage and flying off (***braking***[sic] ***free***), is actually clearly tied to its cage by a string (***stupid line...cage***).

Comment: Well done! I knew the last edit would give it away. :) I wonder how many people were aware of that "line", I just noticed it the other day. I think the music video producers hoped that it was thin enough for people not to notice.